# Calculating $\pi$ using two formulas: $\pi/4 = \arctan(1/2) + \arctan(1/3)$ and $\pi/4 = 4\arctan(1/5) - \arctan(1/239)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, pi

How can I use these two formulas to come up with two infinite series, each of which is used to calculate $\pi$?:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi}4 &= \arctan(1/2) + \arctan(1/3)\\
\frac{\pi}4 &= 4\arctan(1/5) - \arctan(1/239)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: [A related thread.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44595)

Comment: I like $$ \pi = \arctan 1 + \arctan 2 + \arctan 3 $$

Comment: @WillJagy, pretty but $\arctan x$ is easier to compute for $x<1$.

Answer (score 13):

You need the *power series* for $\arctan x$:
$$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\cdots.$$

This power series expansion is often called the *Leibniz series*, although more properly his name should be associated with the pretty but not terribly useful special case $x=1$. The general series was independently discovered by Gregory.  It was also well-known to South Indian mathematicians around $200$ years before Leibniz or Gregory were born.  The name *Nilakantha* is sometimes associated with the discovery, but there is unfortunately no certainty; it may go all the way back to the late fourteenth century mathematician Madhava.   For details on the Kerala school of mathematics, please see [Kim Plofker's book.](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8835.html)

The "Nilakantha" series converges to $\arctan x$ when $-1\le x\le 1$, though  the convergence is hopelessly slow at $x=\pm 1$.

Using $\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\arctan(1/2)+\arctan(1/3)$ we get
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3\cdot 2^3} + \frac{1}{5\cdot 2^5}-\frac{1}{7\cdot 2^7}+\cdots     \right)+ \left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3\cdot 3^3} + \frac{1}{5\cdot 3^5}-\frac{1}{7\cdot 3^7}+\cdots     \right)   .$$
The terms go down reasonably fast.  For each part, the error made when we truncate the infinite series at a certain place is smaller, in absolute value, than the first "neglected" term.

We get better performance from the second formula that you quoted, which is called *Machin's Formula*.  The negative powers of $5$ and $239$ go down much faster than was the case for $2$ and $3$.  Moreover, the fractions $\dfrac{1}{5^{2n+1}}$ are particularly pleasant if we are using decimal arithmetic.

The Machin Formula, and relatives, together with the power series for $\arctan x$, are the method used for most high-precision approximations to $\pi$ from the eighteenth century until now.  Viable alternatives have only emerged recently.

Comment: Ah right, thanks!

Comment: In general, since Maclaurin series converge much faster when their arguments are near zero, it makes sense to use a Machin formula whose arctangent arguments are as small as they can be.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, do you have any references for further reading?

Comment: @AD., you'll want to see [this](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2305526), [this](http://www.jstor.org/pss/3619567), and [this](http://www.jstor.org/pss/40391144).

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, but I was more interested in the historical refs (perhaps it is contained in some of the papers I don't know since I don't have access).

Comment: @AD.: I added a reference to Plofker's Mathematics in India. There is also a fairly recent less scholarly book on Kerala mathematics by George Joseph.

Comment: Thanks André, I will look at this!

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete: To prove the equality 
$$\pi/4 = \arctan(1/2) + \arctan(1/3)$$ consider that $$(2+i)(3+i) =5+5i.$$
Now, taking the arguments of both sides and since the argument of a product is the sum of the arguments of the factors, the equality follows.

Comment: Yes, that was mentioned [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/44625).

Comment: Just to complete: $$\frac{(5+i)^4}{239+i}=2+2i$$