# Euler's Approximation of pi.

Tags: approximation, pi

I recently stumbled across the formula:

$$\pi=20\arctan\frac{1}{7}+8\arctan\frac{3}{79}$$

developed by Euler, for approximating pi. I evaluated it to several thousand decimal places and up to that point, it accurately represented pi.

When does this equation break down in its representation of pi?

Comment: It doesn't. It's an exact identity.

Comment: 2 related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297/simple-numerical-methods-for-calculating-the-digits-of-pi and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/series-that-converge-to-pi-quickly

Comment: A derivation of the identity and related ones can be found [here](http://www.nerdburrow.com/piseries2/)

Comment: Quick proof: The complex number $(7 + i)^{20} (79 + 3 i)^8 = -149011611938476562500000000000000$ lies on the negative real axis, so $20\arctan\frac{1}{7}+8\arctan\frac{3}{79} = \pi + 2\pi n$. Consideration of the sizes of the angles involved shows that $n$ must be zero.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/44625/498) as well.

Comment: $-149011611938476562500000000000000 = 2^{14}5^{40}$, just for info.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That formula doesn't break down.  It can be proven that the right-hand side is equal to $\pi$.  One reason it comes up in connection with *approximation* is that the arctangent terms can be approximated well by adding terms from the Taylor expansion of the arctangent function,

$$\arctan(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^9}{9}-\cdots.$$

This is valid for $|x|\leq 1$, but the series converges more rapidly the closer $x$ is to $0$, so with the relatively small $\frac{1}{7}$ and $\frac{3}{79}$ as inputs it gives a good approximation without having to take too many terms.  This can be contrasted with the formula $$\pi=4\arctan(1)=4\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\cdots\right),$$ where the series converges much more slowly.

---

In 1950 H.C. Schepler published a 3 part "Chronology of pi" in *Mathematics Magazine*, available to those with access to JSTOR [here](http://www.jstor.org/pss/3029284), [here](http://www.jstor.org/pss/3029832), and [here](http://www.jstor.org/pss/3029000). In the second part there is the following excerpt indicating that [Hutton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Hutton) may have suggested using the formula before Euler:

[image]

Schepler's chronology can also be found in L. Berggren, J. Borwein, and P. Borwein's [*Pi: A Source Book*](http://books.google.com/books?id=QlbzjN_5pDoC).

Comment: Thanks for explaining why it's associated with an 'approximation'.  That had me a bit confused

Answer (score 1):

The Soviet 8th grade students usually solve this problem as follows. First, divide by 4. Then a portable arc tangent in the opposite direction. Then calculate the tangent of the right and left part using very simple formula tg(A+B).

Comment: "A portable arc tangent" ... not a correct translation into English of what you want to say.

Comment: What is a portable arc tangent?